# Can't delete my "applications"

Tags: macos, applications

So, I somehow have 40GB worth of applications on my Macbook, but I can't, for the life of me, see what these applications are!

I looked in the *Applications* folder -- there are no apps except the default ones that come installed on the computer. (I made sure to delete the ones I didn't want.)

Under **About This Mac > System Report > System Information**, I can see all these apps installed... but I can't actually uninstall them and they don't show up in my *Applications* folder.

What do I do? I have no idea how to uninstall any of these apps, but 40GB is ridiculous.

Comment: When you say "you can see all these Applications installed" what exactly are you seeing?  Can you post a screenshot?  Remember, we're not there to look over your shoulder.

Answer (score 2):

The 40gb of space being used isn't actually applications there just files on your mac not applications. This has happened to me before, apparently its an indexing problem.
You Can reindex spotlight by going into terminal and typing : `sudo mdutil -E /`

I also would recommend downloading OmniDiskSweeper like mcmahoniel said.
Hope this helps good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[OmniDiskSweeper](https://www.omnigroup.com/more/) is a great tool to help you narrow down where space is being taken up. It's free, and gives you a simply UI (similar to Finder) to drill down and figure that out. See [this article](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how_to_recover_missing_hard_drive_space) for examples.

Alternatively, if you'd like to do it by hand, you can try narrowing down folders one at a time.

For me, I'll right-click (control-click) a set of folders, pick Get Info, and see the space used by each of those folders. I'll dive in deeper into the ones that stand out and do the same for their subfolders.

Repeat until you can see exactly where that space is being taken up.